# Query max date for 3 columns from each data group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query WIP, OUT, TotalOUT by max dateStamp of each Process# and wo.
My issue is I have no idea on query that.

From this data:

| dateStamp | wo | Process# | WIP | OUT | TotalOUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-08 11:10:56 | 140100001143 | 17 | NULL | NULL | 1000 |
| 2022-03-01 08:52:26 | 140100001143 | 18 | 200 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-03-01 08:55:41 | 140100001143 | 18 | 700 | 0 | NULL |
| 2022-03-08 11:15:37 | 140100001143 | 18 | NULL | 300 | NULL |
| 2022-03-08 11:15:48 | 140100001143 | 18 | NULL | NULL | 1000 |
| 2022-03-01 08:52:26 | 140100001143 | 19 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-03-08 11:15:55 | 140100001143 | 19 | NULL | NULL | 1000 |
| 2022-03-01 08:52:26 | 140100001143 | 20 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-03-01 18:08:04 | 140100001143 | 20 | 300 | 100 | NULL |

To this data

| wo | Process# | WIP | OUT | TotalOUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 140100001143 | 17 | NULL | NULL | 1000 |
| 140100001143 | 18 | 700 | 300 | 1000 |
| 140100001143 | 19 | NULL | NULL | 1000 |
| 140100001143 | 20 | 1000 | 100 | NULL |

This is the code I've got so far.

```
select dateStamp, wo, Process#, WIP, OUT, TotalOUT 
from  [dbo].[ANTS_WIP] t1
where dateStamp = (
    select max(dateStamp)
    from  [dbo].[ANTS_WIP] t2
    where t1.wo = t2.wo and t1.wip = t2.WIP
)
```

Comment: Why is the expected result for Process #18- | 700 | 300 | 1000 | ? Is that a typo?

Comment: SOS thank you for intention. This is not typo. 700, 300, 1000 is the max date of WIP, OUT, TotalOUT of process#18.

Comment: @Dale K   Thank you for helping me reformat my table and the code blog.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a case for `last_value() IGNORE NULLS`. Unforturnatley only Azure version of the Sql Sever supports the `IGNORE NULLS` option. You can use 3 derived tables instead

```
select t1.wo, t1.Process#, t1.maxdateStamp, tw.lastv WIP, tout.lastv OUT, tto.lastv TotalOut
from (
  select Process#, wo, max(dateStamp) maxdateStamp
  from tbl
  group by Process#, wo
  ) t1
left join (
  select distinct Process#, wo, last_Value(WIP) 
        over(partition by wo, Process# order by dateStamp rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) lastv 
  from tbl
  where WIP is not null
) tw on t1.Process# = tw.Process# and t1.wo = tw.wo
left join (
  select distinct Process#, wo, last_Value(OUT) 
        over(partition by wo, Process# order by dateStamp rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) lastv
  from tbl
  where OUT is not null
) tout on t1.Process# = tout.Process# and t1.wo = tout.wo
left join (
  select distinct Process#, wo, last_Value(TotalOUT) 
        over(partition by wo, Process# order by dateStamp rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) lastv
  from tbl
  where TotalOUT is not null
) tto on t1.Process# = tto.Process# and t1.wo = tto.wo
order by t1.wo, t1.Process#
```

Comment: Serg. I have tested (now with asc dsc number vice versa). Yes it works. Thanks a lot.